# How to print the output value of a column by fixing a particular corresponding reference value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

```
  A       B       C

 x=value at C corresponding to A at 0.5

 0      5655     0
 0.25   6757     545
 0.5    7856     5776
 0.75   9866     5644
```

please help me to print the value (say 'x') at somewhere in column B (say B2). It should select the value of column C always corresponding to 0.5 at column A and the 0.5 value will be fluctuating from 1 place to another depending on the input steps given. so whatever it may be, the final output must always be the value corresponding to 0.5

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) formula. In short, it does exactly what you want - matches a value in one column and returns the value in a column to the right. In this case, assuming your formula is in cell `D2`, try this:

```
=VLOOKUP(0.5, A:C, 3, FALSE)
```

This will look for the value 0.5 in column A and return the corresponding value in column C. Note that it will return the first match if there are multiple 0.5's.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
Sub UseSelection()
    Dim r As Long

    r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Range("A1").Select
    Do Until Selection.Row > r
    If Selection.Value = 0.5 Then
        Range("B2") = Range("C" & Selection.Row).Value
    End If
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Or using Vlookup:

```
Sub UseVlookup()
    Range("B2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(0.5, Range("A:C"), 3, False)
End Sub
```

Or,

```
Sub Another()
    Range("B2") = "=VLOOKUP(0.5,A:C,3,FALSE)"
End Sub
```

Or put the formula in the cell itself (not flexible)

```
=VLOOKUP(0.5,A:C,3,FALSE)
```